# How to use wildcards in sub collection names in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have a lot of sub-collections within my main collection in Firestore. The sub collection names are like: image_1, image_2, 123_image_3 etc. Each of these sub-collections have documents with different fields. I want to export these to Cloud Storage.

Is there any way through which I can pass the sub collection names by using wildcards or anything else? I have more than 50 sub collections containing the string 'image' in their names and I cannot manually pass every name in my firestore export command.

command:
gcloud firestore export gs://bucket_name/image --collection-ids='%image%' this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available option to export specific collections is by using the feature `--collection-ids`, which allows you to set specific collections and sub-collections to be exported - as indicated in the official documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_specific_collections).

Considering that, unfortunately, it's not possible to achieve what you are trying to do to. For this reason, I would recommend you to raise a Feature Request in [Google's Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), so they can check the possibility of implementing this in the future.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Yes, this helps! Also, is there any command which can help me get the names of all the subcollections within all my documents? I have over 500 docs within my parent collection  and each of these documents have subcollections with different names. I want to get a list of these subcollection names.

Comment: Hi @NehaShaikh great to hear that it helped you! There is not command, but you can create a simple application to return the names. In this page you have some examples: [How to list all subcollections of a Cloud Firestore document?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-list-all-subcollections-of-a-cloud-firestore-document-17f2bb80a166)